# Android intents are launched in reverse order

Tags: android, android-intent, stack

I am working on an android app where I from one activity create and start a number of activities using intents (and close these using the finish() method()) however when I run the app the order the activities are launched in is the reversed of the creation order. I realize this is because the intents are not launched imminently on the startActivity(Intent) call, but added to a queue, but I would really like to preserve the order. My question is, is there any way to keep the order of the activities as they are created? See pseudo code for better explanation

```
**Main Class**

Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, activity1);
startActivity(intent1);


Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, activity2);
startActivity(intent2);


Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, activity3);
startActivity(intent3);



**Intent class**
 ....
 finish()
```

However when I launch the app the activity 3 is launched first, followed by 2 and finally 1 ---> how do I preserve the order so they launch 1->2->3?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: If you need that degree of control, why are you using activities? Shouldn't this be one activity with a few fragments?

Answer (score 1):

You can start first activity, in it's onCreate(...) method start second and then in onCreate(...) of second activity start third. So you will get 1->2->3 and 3 will be on the top of the stack